# Need help in implementing Paypal IPN on localhost

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am stuck at IPN Notifications which are returned from Paypal. We need a live hosting service for this purpose. I have chosen free hosting service (000webhost.com). However, there are many issues related to it.

I have also read various posts on stackoverflow to implement IPN on localhost 
using ngrok (https://ngrok.com) (creating a tunnel for my localhost to outside world),but to no avail.

Can I get a fully working solution to test IPN on localhost ?

Below are the links of various posts which I have referred :
[Can I test paypal api's from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510995/can-i-test-paypal-apis-from-localhost)
[Using Paypal IPN with website running on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980371/using-paypal-ipn-with-website-running-on-localhost)

Comment: What is wrong with using ngrok?

Answer (score 0):

"Can I get a fully working solution to test IPN on localhost ?" - no, because paypal cant hit a url not globally available

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure your local server is accessible via public IP address.

You could do this using a dynamic DNS service, for example, or you could create a subdomain that points directly to your public IP address (ie. ipn.mydomain.com)

If your IP changes you'd have to update the DNS record, of course, but that usually doesn't happen very often anyway.

With something like that setup you'll need to make sure your local routers / firewalls are configured to allow HTTP traffic through, and then you can use the domain you have setup as a URL to your server, which could then be used to configure IPN in PayPal so that it will work.